# Can I use EventMachine in cloud foundry?

Tags: eventmachine, cloud-foundry

When I start a program which uses EventMachine, the vmc start does not return whether it succeed or not. It seems just time out.

But,I do see "the server started" in my log file. So I am wondering what is proper way to use EventMachine in cloud foundry?

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail with regard to the context in which you are using EventMachine. What kind of a Ruby application are you using it in? and what gems are you using in conjunction with EventMachine? Caldecott, the app used for tunnelling in CloudFoundry uses EventMachine, so I don't see why this should be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Eventmachine does work in Cloud Foundry, it's a dependency on thin which if included in a project can be used to serve Rack / Rails apps.